# Examples of Common Emitter Circuits

Tags: transistors, bjt, common-emitter

I want to practice more bipolar transistor, more specific Common Emitters.
Can someone give me any source where there are exercises with solutions of Common Emitter Circuits .

i just want to go  exercise and go through them and then check if I have done them correctly

Comment: You can expect the same results as in [How many NPN common emitter transistor circuits are there? **on hold**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/447005/how-many-npn-common-emitter-transistor-circuits-are-there). Please don't post duplicates.

Comment: I was hoping for any links or websites where I can visit ?

Comment: @Ed1995 I have pages of such schematics that I got from a teacher at Tektronix, perhaps 40 years ago. There were about 8 or 10 problems on each page. It was very good for me to work through them. So I understand your request. If I knew of a web page as good as what I remember from Tektronix, I'd point you there. But I don't know of one. You might visit MIT's site (they make some of their coursework free online.) Or some other school, perhaps. If I find my pages here (I need to sort through some stuff) someday, I may develop such a web site and be able to point you. But not now, sadly.

Comment: Yes. I really appreciate the answer people are giving but they are not pointing me anywhere. I have look hundreds of pages and since this a place for electronics I thought people will point me to different website.